# Instagram.com/username/media no longer working

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, instagram

I created a small web app a few months ago that would create stylized instagram galleries for public profiles by accessing the JSON from instagram.com/username/media (not via the API). I went to my personal website today and realized that the gallery was not working. When I began troubleshooting I realized the issue was with this link. I now get "page not found". Has instagram changed the link to access a profile's JSON data, or have they removed this entirely outside of the API?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of images from Instagram for explicit user account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238978/get-list-of-images-from-instagram-for-explicit-user-account)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSON data has been moved to another URL: https://www.instagram.com/{USER_NAME}/?__a=1

Comment: Thank you! Just for future reference, is this officially documented anywhere by instagram?

Comment: @itsseanl It's not an official endpoint. I suppose it's only for their website only.

Comment: For next 12 images, use ID of the last item (`maxId = media.nodes[11].id`) in the `max_id` param: `https://www.instagram.com/{USER_NAME}/?__a=1&max_id={maxId}`

Comment: I am not able to get any data using this url, is it still working ?